# bdd(specflow) and tfs build?

Tags: bdd, tfsbuild, specflow

I manage to use bddlib(storyq) with combination of xunit.net using resharper runner. Than decided to try to specflow, since have read its advantages over storyq.
Now  I do have also another requirement to integrate this all with tfs build 2010. Am bit lost there how the big picture gonna look like. I found some articles on how to make work xunit.net with tfsbuild 2010, however there is no single word on bdd lib integration with tfsbuild  more specifically continuous integration (ci).

Anyone could have helped ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run it from the command-line you can simply customize your TFS Build workflow by tossing an InvokeProcess activity in there.  An example of customizing the workflow can be seen here: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/28/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-3-Use-more-complex-arguments.aspx

Comment: thanks Dylan. i ended up with same approach and finally can get the xunit test results from tfsbuild. the other question which left open is how to use storq or any bdd tool with this ci stack(xunit.net + tfsbuild). i used to run storyq from resharper but have no idea how it should be run with continuous integration.